# How can I use @beforestory annotation in my tests

Tags: jbehave

I am automating my tests with Jbehave.

I used certain annotation, now I want to do certain setup before executing the story.

For example

If I have 5 user stories then I should have 5 @before story annotation which will do the different tasks.

Can anybody guide me how can I achieve this?

I went through Google search but did not get proper solution.

Remember it's about @BeforeStory and not for @BeforeStories.

Thanks in Advance

Chetan!

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using @BeforeStory annotation, because a method annotated with this annotation is executed before each story - for all executed stories.
However You can use a `lifecycle before` step in your stories, please take a look at [this](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/story-syntax.html) example:

```
A story is a collection of scenarios

Narrative:
In order to communicate effectively to the business some functionality
As a development team
I want to use Behaviour-Driven Development


Lifecycle:
Before:
Given a step that is executed before each scenario
After:
Outcome: ANY   
Given a step that is executed after each scenario regardless of outcome
Outcome: SUCCESS
Given a step that is executed after each successful scenario
Outcome: FAILURE
Given a step that is executed after each failed scenario

Scenario:  A scenario is a collection of executable steps of different type

Given step represents a precondition to an event
When step represents the occurrence of the event
Then step represents the outcome of the event
```

Pay attention to `Lifecycle: Before:` keywords:

```
Lifecycle:
Before:
Given a step that is executed before each scenario
```

The `given` step that is next to these keywords will be executed before each scenario in this story - but only for scenarios in this story, not in other stories.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this out then come to you in case of any issue